# JSF Navigation case not worked in IE

Tags: tomcat, jsf-2, navigation, richfaces

In my sample application using JSF2.0 + richfaces3.3.3 + tomcat6.0.29.

My navigation case without redirect not worked in IE. 
But other browser worked.

When i add **redirect** tag, then page navigation working in all browser.

JSF1.2, i am not use redirect, page navigation works fine in all browser.

**Why JSF2.0 need redirect tag?**

My jsp file location **webpages/design/first.jsp** and **webpages/design/second.jsp**

faces-config.xml

```
....
....
 <managed-bean>        
    <managed-bean-name>First</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>sample.First</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>

<navigation-rule>        
    <from-view-id>/design/first.jsp</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>go_secondpage</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/design/second.jsp</to-view-id>

    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>


....
```

**webpages/design/first.jsp**

```
<f:view>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>First Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <h:form id="sampleForm">

            <h:panelGrid cellpadding="10" cellspacing="10">

                <h:outputText value="You are in first page"/>
                <a4j:commandButton value="GO-SecondPage" action="#{First.goSecondPage}"/>

            </h:panelGrid>

        </h:form>

    </body>
</html>
```

**First.java**

```
package sample;
public class First
{
    public String goSecondPage()
    {
        String message = "go_secondpage";
        return message;
    }
}
```

**webpages/design/second.jsp**

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Seocnd Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome second page</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Help me.
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

you are using richfaces version with limited support for JSF2 check [link](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/RichFaces333AndJSF20). Remove richfaces tag, use pure JSF command button tag and check and if using richfaces with JSF2 use version 4.x. Its not JSF issue. Also see you are using proper faces-config.xml according to JSF version.